# Find process and write to it

Tags: java, process

I want to find a process and write to it in Java. I'm running a program with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\myProgram.exe -command");
```

I've tried to use `OutputStream`, which doesn't seem to work for my program. My guess is that my program creates a new process which I can't access from the one I made. (The program is a game if it's of any need)

So, I want to fetch the process by using it's ID or name which I'm able to fetch, but I can't figure out how to get the process object. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you're asking.

Comment: Thought so too, since I can't find anything about it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it can be done, but it would require JNI or JNA or use of another non-core Java utility to allow you to get closer to the OS.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm pretty sure I can't go writing to an arbitrary process's STDIN stream. If it is pointing to a TTY maybe, but this is Windows - I'm not sure how this could work.

Comment: You can't write to a process you didn't start yourself. Try getting rid of the 'cmd /c' part.